# Hadoop disk usage (intermediate reduce)

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-partitioning

I' new in Hadoop,
I'm using a cluster and I have a disk quote of 15GB.
If I try to execute the **wordcount sample** on a big dataset (about 25GB) I receveid always the exception "The DiskSpace quota of xxxx is exceeded: ".

I checked my disk usage after exception and it is so far from the quote.
Is this due to the temporary files or intermediate jobs?
Is possible to delete temporary/intermediate files?

(I can modifify the configuration by Java code, I have no access directy to the .xml configaration file)

Thanks! ;)

Comment: I would increase the disk quota. 15 GB isn't big data. You can fit this in the main memory of a PC these days.  Most likely you are prevented from trying to use 25 GB which is why you are not using even close to that amount.

Comment: What is your usage before you start the job? How much data are you outputting? If the key and value are small (a single word and a single int) it should not result in large temporary files. These temporary files are deleted once the job completes.